# Using HttpHandler (ashx) to serve images

Tags: image, httphandler

I'm trying to implement an httphandler to serve images. I've seen plenty of examples and the process seems simple enough. However, it seems that my image tag

```
<img src="ImageHandler.ashx?picture=moon.jpg" />
```

persists in interpreting the call to the handler as a straight URL. ImageHandler.ashx is in the App_Code folder. I figure the problem is in registering the handler. Here's my current web.config entry (I've tried lots of them, includeing *.jpg as the path.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ImageHandler" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="ImageHandler" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" />
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio decided that the ashx file needed to be TWO files. I knew that was going on. However, what I didn't know (until I tried copying the files into and out of the App_Code folder) was that having the ashx file in the app root and the ashx.vb file in the App_Code folder would make the handler work - without needing to register it in the web.config file. Never seen anything like it.